# "Unhandled stream error in pipe" and "ENOTDIR: not a directory, open" when running Gulp

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp, nfs, vagrant-windows

I'm running a laravel application on homestead on a windows 8 machine.

I use gulp, elixix and node.js to compile resource files like SASS and .js files.

When I run the gulp command, I/O errors occur:

```
    Saving To...
       - ../www/css/admin.css

stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/home/vagrant/projects/site/www/css/admin.css'
    at Error (native)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises when I enable NFS on homestead.

The fix that worked for me was to disable NFS (temporarily) in the homestead.yaml file :

```
folders:
    - map: C:\projects
      to: /home/vagrant/projects
      #type: nfs  -->> comment these lines
      #mount_options: [nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1] -->> comment these lines
```

run vagrant reload --provision to apply the changes and run gulp again.

I spent hours finding a fix for this, I hope this can save some users the frustration.

Comment: Is there any way to run nfs (windows) with gulp? Without nfs option homestead is very slow :(